# dialog box having map inside pager fragment in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am developing application and getting an error null for access fragment from dialog layout file inside dialog. Actually I want to show map inside a dialog box on click of list view inside a  pager fragment.

dialog layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/mapevent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Close"
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Fragment file and dialog where I am attaching dialog. its working while I am trying to get map object to add marker then I am not getting object of Support map fragment

```
public class Event extends Fragment {
private ListView listView;
.
.
.
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_three, container, false);
   if(map_dialog==null)
    map_dialog= new Dialog(getActivity());

    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_list);
    dialog.show();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
           dialog.show();

            map_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            map_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
            map_dialog.show();

            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
            FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
             mMapView = (SupportMapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mMapView.onCreate(map_dialog.onSaveInstanceState());
            mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately
            mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

                    latLng=new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(eventList.get(position).getLat()),Double.parseDouble(eventList.get(position).getLng()));
                    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: post the crash log....

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
mMapView = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mapevent);
```

For dialog, you can use `MapView` instead of `SupportMapFragment`.

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map" />
```

Do this in your `Fragment`:

```
MapView mMapView;


listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

        dialog.show();

        map_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        map_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
        map_dialog.show();

        mMapView = (MapView) map_dialog.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(map_dialog.savedInstanceState);
        mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

                latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(eventList.get(position).getLat()),Double.parseDouble(eventList.get(position).getLng()));
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: not working I have already checked it you just changed Id actually I forgot to write but I am using same id both side. But thanks for try and efforts

Comment: mMapView = (MapView) map_dialog.findViewById(R.id.map);